# React JS - Dynamic modal rendering

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-context

I am attempting to create a dynamic modal that can render different content based on specific requirements. So far, I have developed the following code, but I'm uncertain whether this is the correct approach or if the code is well-written.

Modal Context:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Component1 from '../components/Component1';
import Component2 from '../components/Component2';

type ComponentType = 'Component1' | 'Component2';

const ModalContext = createContext({
  isModalVisible: false,
  showModal: (data: { type: ComponentType }) => {},
  hideModal: () => {},
  modalToDisplay: null as { type: ComponentType } | null,
  components: {} as Record<ComponentType, React.ElementType>,
});

export function ModalProvider({ children }: any) {
  const [modalToDisplay, setModalToDisplay] = useState<{ type: ComponentType } | null>(null);
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const components: Record<ComponentType, React.ElementType> = {
    'Component1': Component1,
    'Component2': Component2,
  };
  
  const showModal = (modal: { type: ComponentType }) => {
    setModalToDisplay(modal);
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setModalToDisplay(null);
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('modalToDisplay', modalToDisplay);
  },[modalToDisplay]);

  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={{ modalToDisplay, isModalVisible, showModal, hideModal, components }}>
      {children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useModal() {
  const context = useContext(ModalContext);
  return context;
}
```

Custom Modal:

```
import React from 'react';
type ComponentType = 'Component1' | 'Component2';

type ModalProps = {
  modalToDisplay: { type: ComponentType } | null;
  components: Record<ComponentType, React.ElementType>;
};

const Modal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({ modalToDisplay, components }) => {
  if (modalToDisplay) {
    const ModalComponent = components[modalToDisplay.type];
    return <ModalComponent />;
  }
  return null;
};


export default Modal;
```

Fake modal component:

```
import { useModal } from '../context/ModalContext';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { Modal } from 'antd';

function Component1() {
  const { hideModal , showModal } = useModal();

  return (
      <Modal
        title="TEST1"
        open={true}
        onOk={hideModal}
        onCancel={hideModal}
        footer={<Button onClick={() => showModal({ type: 'Component2'})  }>Show modal 2</Button>}
      >
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
      </Modal>
  );
}

export default Component1;
```

Test Button:

```
import { useModal } from '../context/ModalContext'; 
import Modal from './CustomModal';

const ModalOpener = () => {
  const { showModal, isModalVisible, modalToDisplay, components } = useModal();

  const handleOpenModal = () => {
    showModal({ type: 'Component1' }); 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleOpenModal}>Open Modal</button>
      {
        isModalVisible && (
          <Modal modalToDisplay={modalToDisplay} components={components} />
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default ModalOpener;
```

App:

```
import { ModalProvider } from './context/ModalContext';
import ModalOpener from './components/Button';

function App() {
  
  return (
    <ModalProvider>
       <ModalOpener />
    </ModalProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is this a good idea? Do you know a better way of doing this?
Thank you!